# Permissions to set for Secure internet browsing in Windows 10 (Pro)

Tags: account-security, windows-10, windows-permissions

In the recent past I have been a victim of virus/malware attacks on my home computer running Windows 10 (Home), since I used the same account with high access rights to also browse the internet. However, to mitigate the risks I have upgraded to Windows 10 (Professional) and have also created a **standard-user** specifically for internet browsing with the intention to secure internet access and shield against virus/malware attacks etc on my computer.

So, I intend to be cognizant about what permissions should I set for this new "standard"-user (e.g. file-security permissions, read/write/control file/resource access etc) to browse the internet safely and prevent virus/malware from modifying files, accessing resources or writing itself on my computer. (BTW, It should still allow the user to browse the internet).

Can anyone please point me in the right direction and provide steps/best practices for security on Windows? E.g. deny/allow access to files/resources specifically, other security settings that should be enabled, for safe internet browsing on my computer running Windows 10 (Professional)? Also, kindly let me know which antivirus or any other apps is better suited for home computers.

I understand that this question is very wide and open-ended, but, still if someone could provide some basic ideas like which files to restrict access to, general allow/deny permissions, common security settings etc that could protect my desktop.

Kindly let me know if additional information is required.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is really a discussion chocked full of opinions, suggestions, positions, guesses, and *what about gotchas*. Despite the voice in my head chanting, "Don't Do It ... Don't Do it ..." I'm going to make some observations.

*Yes I know, this doesn't answer the question.*

As far as Internet Browsing is concerned, there is no effective difference between Windows *Home* and *Pro*. Perhaps you're thinking bitlocker encryption is a protection factor, it's not in this circumstance.

The Microsoft provided Malware/Virus protection is highly rated. It's easiest to stick with that.

Creating a non-admin User account and using that is highly recommended.

Most malware infections these days do not come from direct Browser interactions or exploits. Modern Browsers do an excellent job of living within operational security constraints. The classic click a link and get infected would be a rare 0-Day you are unlikely to ever encounter. Personally, I recommend using a non-Microsoft Browser because it is not tied so tightly with the operating system, but that is arguably a personal bias.

The fact that you've encountered malware compromises in the past suggests your usage habits need evaluating.

**Malware infection onto you machine is *almost always* because you chose to execute a dubious program.**

So how does that happen?

- A pop-up - *Malware detected from your machine. Run this cleaner.*
  **No! Just No!**
- *Your Browser cannot play this video. Allow this video player to install in order to play this video.* **No!**
- *Your machine has been detected doing bad things. Allow repair access?* **No!**
- *Girls waiting for you. Click and allow Hotgirls.Bikini.Huge.Waiting.jpg.**exe** .* **No!**
- "*Dude, look at the awesome program on this thumb drive my bud gave
  me.*" **No!**

If you feel you need to run dubious programs, do it on a disposable machine.